# Is it safe to install Compiz Experimental Plugins 0.1.1 on Maverick?

Tags: 10.10, compiz, plugins

Does anyone have these plugins installed? Sorry, but I'm worried, because my past attempts to update compiz have failed, and when I try to install these plugins they ask to me to update these files:

```
  compiz-dev compiz-fusion-bcop debhelper html2text intltool-debian
  libcairo-gobject2 libcairo2-dev libdecoration0-dev libdrm-dev libexpat1-dev
  libfontconfig1-dev libfreetype6-dev libgl1-mesa-dev libglu1-mesa-dev
  libice-dev libkms1 libmail-sendmail-perl libpango1.0-dev libpixman-1-dev
  libpng12-dev libsm-dev libstartup-notification0-dev
  libsys-hostname-long-perl libx11-xcb-dev libxcb-render0-dev libxcb-shm0-dev
  libxcomposite-dev libxcursor-dev libxdamage-dev libxext-dev libxfixes-dev
  libxft-dev libxinerama-dev libxml2-dev libxrandr-dev libxrender-dev
  libxslt1-dev libxss-dev mesa-common-dev po-debconf x11proto-composite-dev
  x11proto-damage-dev x11proto-fixes-dev x11proto-randr-dev
  x11proto-render-dev x11proto-scrnsaver-dev x11proto-xext-dev
  x11proto-xinerama-dev
```

Please answer my question, and I'll be very grateful!

[These Plugins are here](http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/Compiz+Experimental+Plugins+32+%26+64+Bit?content=118511&PHPSESSID=56e734eae2112ca419582f4660eb9926)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of those packages are development packages required to build the plugins, it is never safe to install software using a random script.

Comment: I have used the script and it isn't so random...